# IntelliJ IDEA: how to disable projects opening as tabs on macOS?

Tags: intellij-idea

No idea since when this was introduced but recently updated to Monterey and it started to appear.

How can I disable it? I prefer one editor per workspace. The new way conflicts with normal tab switching.

Comment: Does https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/use-tabs-in-windows-mchla4695cce/mac help?

Comment: @CrazyCoder probably, will test later. Weird feature as it conflicts with other tab shortcuts in the editor itself.

Comment: Interesting but now I have no tabs feature in Finder.. fcuk.

Comment: Is there not a way to disable this just for Intellij?

Comment: The tabs does look like Intellij's own design and x buttons.

Comment: IDE is using the system setting. You can try `ide.mac.bigsur.window.with.tabs.enabled=false` in Help | Edit Custom Properties and restart the IDE.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Either disable it [globally in macOS system settings](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/use-tabs-in-windows-mchla4695cce/mac), or disable it for IntelliJ IDEA only by adding `ide.mac.bigsur.window.with.tabs.enabled=false` in Help | Edit Custom Properties (IDE restart is required).

Comment: Thank you! it finally solved it!

Comment: This is the most beautiful poem has written. I LOVE YOU TOO @CrazyCoder!!!